# Retrieve arguments passed to mocked function with Mockito

Tags: python, mocking, mockito

I am using mockito to patch an instance of some class and check the calls on the method of this class.

With this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def foo(self, a):
        self.a = 2 * a
        return 2 * a
```

I can use mockito to patch `foo` like this:

```
instance = A(1)
mockito.expect(instance, times=1).foo(a=5).thenReturn(10)
```

This allows me to verify that foo has been called with the argument `5` once. I can also use `...` instead of `a=5` to verify it is called once with any argument.

What I would like to do is verify it has been called once with an argument that can be divided by 2. I have two ideas for this (and I have no idea how to implement either):

1. Pass some sort of lambda function instead of the argument `a=5`. I believe I have seen something like this in mockito for Java.
2. Use `...` and retrieve the arguments passed on call to `foo`. This way I can do my verifications on those easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try `arg_that`, where you can pass in a lambda:

From the [documentation](https://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the-matchers.html#:%7E:text=mockito.matchers.arg_that):

> mockito.matchers.arg_that(predicate)
>
> Matches any argument for which predicate returns True
> Example:
>
> verify(mock).foo(arg_that(lambda arg: arg > 3 and arg < 7))